# Spring Boot Application class does not existed in the test module(JPMS)

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-platform-module-system, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I tried to use Java 9+ built-in JPMS(Java Platform Module System) to modulize a Spring Boot application, check [the complete sample codes here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/modular-jpms).

In IDEA, when running the tests, it worked well.

But when I ran it via `mvn clean verify` in the root folder, and the `greeting.application.test` will fail due to an exception "can not find the package `com.example.greeting.application` and class `GreetingApplication`".

```sh
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project greeting-application-test: Compilation failure: Compilation fai
lure:
[ERROR] /D:/hantsylabs/spring-puzzles/modular-jpms/greeting-application-test/src/main/java/com/example/greeting/application/test/GreetingApplicationTests.java:[3,40] package com.exampl
e.greeting.application does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/hantsylabs/spring-puzzles/modular-jpms/greeting-application-test/src/main/java/com/example/greeting/application/test/GreetingApplicationTests.java:[13,19] cannot find symbo
l
[ERROR]   symbol: class GreetingApplication
```

The *module-info.java* in the *greeting.application.test* like this.

```java
module greeting.application.test {
    requires greeting.application;

    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.context;

    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.webflux;

    requires spring.test;
    requires spring.boot.test;
    requires spring.boot.test.autoconfigure;

    requires org.junit.jupiter;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.params;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.engine;
    requires org.junit.platform.commons;
    requires org.assertj.core;
    requires org.mockito.junit.jupiter;
    requires transitive net.bytebuddy;

    opens com.example.greeting.application.test  to spring.core, org.junit.platform.commons;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not really with a "test" module, but any other module trying to access the application you have built.

This is caused by `spring-boot-maven-plugin` used to **`repackage`** the maven module `greeting-application` corresponding to its java module.

The [#Classifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging.examples.custom-classifier) section in the documentation talks about the reason clearly further(highlighted by me):

> By default, the repackage goal replaces the original artifact with the
> repackaged one. That is a sane behavior for modules that represent an
> application but **if your module is used as a dependency of another
> module, you need to provide a classifier for the repackaged one**. The
> reason for that is that application classes are packaged in
> BOOT-INF/classes so that the dependent module cannot load a repackaged
> jar’s classes.

Hence, in order to fix the issue, you could work out with

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Quoting the documentation further and relative to the config update:

*This configuration will generate two artifacts: the original one and the repackaged counter part produced by the repackage goal. Both will be installed/deployed transparently.*